# Create new CSV first iteration and append in next iterations

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, append

Now my code always appending to a file, but during the first iteration of for loop I need to create an empty file.
my code looks like this

```
import csv, pyodbc
MDBList = ['C:/Users/vignesh.rajendran/Desktop/Test-results_new.mdb','C:\SVN\CKMotorData\Classes\Test-results.mdb']
DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'
PWD = ''
def ReadMDB (MDBList):
    for path in MDBList:
        MDB = path
        con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={};DBQ={};PWD={}'.format(DRV,MDB,PWD))
        cur = con.cursor() 
        SQL = 'SELECT * FROM CK_Test_Results;' # your query goes here
        rows = cur.execute(SQL).fetchall()
        cur.close(); con.close()
        with open("MDBcombined.csv", 'a', newline='') as fou:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(fou) # default field-delimiter is ","
            csv_writer.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way you could achieve this could be by taking advantage of the [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function (in order for you to have a counter within the `for` loop):

```
import csv, pyodbc
MDBList = ['C:/Users/vignesh.rajendran/Desktop/Test-results_new.mdb','C:\SVN\CKMotorData\Classes\Test-results.mdb']
DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'
PWD = ''
def ReadMDB (MDBList):
    for counter,path in enumerate(MDBList):
        if counter == 0:
            ###Create empty file in the first iteration of the loop
            with open('YOUR-AWESOME-NEW-FILE.csv', 'w') as fp: 
            pass
...
```

I wrote the code above just to mention you how you could execute a command once within the `for` loop depending on the iteration (with the `if` statement and the `counter`) as that seems to be the basis of your question, nonetheless another approach you could take would be to create the empty file outside the `for` loop and only use the for loop to append the lines to the file.

Answer (score -1):

i think you should open it in write mode instead of append mode in write mode it creates a file `with open("MDBcombined.csv", 'w+', newline='')`  
may be this helps.

Comment: i need append mode only as i have to append all in the list